# How to animate an element and not lose border-radius?

Tags: html, css, animation, webkit, keyframe

I've got a little animation on a center-piece image, it zooms in a bit and then returns to its original size.

[Code here!](http://jsfiddle.net/wije/jWLtT/)

Trouble is, the animation "overrides" the border radius on the parent element even though it has overflow hidden on it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Webkit. `overflow: hidden` does not hide a transformed element's overflow on the corners. For more information have a look at https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67950.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `background-color` of your `.image` class expands upto the `#promo` and covers up the `border-radius` set by `pane` class.

You have to set:

```
background-color: transparent; //in image class,
```

and,

```
background-color: #91bd09;
```

in your `pane` class.

See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWLtT/2/).

Comment: If you put the image in there, you'd still have a problem. Notice how the text still shows outside of the border.

Comment: Well I am not CSS ninja...So thank you for your info :) I just try out with the `border` part, it gives me positive result which i said here..next time will take care.. :)